# "Is to complete" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'd like to understand what does *is to complete* mean in the following phrase:

> *Is it stated (in the Quality Plan) that the Qulity Plan **is to complete** the generic Quality Manual with disposals for methods, procedures and materials  specific to the Product concerned?*

I need to understand is the relation of the documents listed above (Quality Plan and generic Quality Manual) subordination or they are supplementary to each other.

Another way I could answer the question whether it be:

1. "Is it stated (in the Quality Plan) that the Quality Plan made to fullfill the requirements stated in generic Quality Plan regarding disposal for methods, procedures and materials specific to the Product concerned?"
2. "Is it stated (in the Quality Plan) that the Quality Plan made in addition to generic Quality Manual defines requirements regarding disposal for methods, procedures and materials specific to the Product concerned." Or "So did you difine methods, procedures etc. specific to the Product concerned in the Quality Plan whether it is required in generic Quality Manual or not."

The answer is realy depends of the meaning "is to complete" put by author:

1. Situation 1 where I must define in Quality Plan what generic Quality Manual require to define via Quality Plan. If there is no requirements to define anything about methods, procedures etc. and it is not defined in Quality Plan, then the answer is "Yes, I did define everithing that generic Quality Plan require frome me to define (i.e. nothing but it is "yes" in term of logic)"
2. Situation 2 where I must define in Quality Plan methods, procedures etc. in addition to what is stated in generic Quality Manual as to be defined via Quality Plan. In this case if gengeric Quality Manual requires me nothing to define via Quality Plan and I did define nothing then the answer is "No, I did not difine in Quality Plan any methods, procedure etc. in addition to what is stated in generic Quality Manual via Quality Plan."

The trick is that generic Quality Manual could be any kind. It can have any reqirments to the Quality Plan and could not - case by case. And I want to understand what do they want from me - "did you followed the Manual?" or "Did you defined the listed stuff anyway?"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? Where did you read the phrase? Does the phrase actually say X and Y or you use them to replace the original words? The grammar of this phrase doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: The grammar is from the oficial document of native english speaking company as far as I know. The X is Quality Plan and Y is Quality Manual and 1,2,3 is a citation of material, man, mthodes, resourceds etc, specific for the Product concerned.

Comment: Right now, the segment you've posted is phrased as a question, but doesn't seem to be intended that way. Can you post more of the surrounding sentences to make the meaning clearer? As it stands, it's nonsense.

Comment: I think you can substitute *will complete* there or *is intended to complete* if the outcome is not certain.

Comment: It's English, Jim, but not as we know it... The writer should be sentenced to reading European Community directives for the rest of his or her days.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "is to complete" (which really has the sense of "is intended to complete") means simply that the (product-independent) Quality Manual while necessary is not sufficient to cover all quality aspects pertaining to the product in question.

In other words the Quality Manual is only a portion of everything that's needed. The rest of what is needed is the (product-dependent) Quality *Plan*, which fills in the gaps left by the QM (or, depending on how the QM is written, the QP may *override* some QM provisions).

And so, in that context the Quality Plan completes the Quality Manual.